# Public address for RDS not available from EC2 app?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am trying to establish a Spring boot EC2 application to access a separate RDS (mysql) database. I have created the database ok and am able to access it from mysqlworkbench and from my spring boot app running on my local machine. However when I deploy the spring boot app to EC2 it fails to connect to the database, see the error log below.

Is there some configuration I have omitted which would allow the application to talk to the database?
Alternatively, how can I go about debugging what is happening, is there a way I can remotely debug the app?

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar!/:5.1.45]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar!/:5.1.45]
    ... 67 common frames omitted

2018-04-13 17:10:49.481  WARN 28264 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2018-04-13 17:10:49.498  INFO 28264 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: Are you using the right credentials? Is the 3306 port is enabled in the given security group? Do the EC2 and the RDS in the same security group? If not the security group can reach each other?

Comment: Ha ha, somewhere in there is my answer! I have tested that I have the correct url, password etc set as I am able to access the database from outside AWS with those settings.
I think it's the security I have setup wrong, but I cannot work out how to do it!

Comment: Can you show the security setting? Maybe we can work things out.

Comment: Well, on the app I don't really have any security settings.
On the RDS I have one security group with types of CIDR/IP - inbound & CIDR/IP - Outbound. The first has an ip address and the second is all zeros ( 0.0.0.0/0 ). I confess I don't really understand this stuff!

Comment: What is the inbound rule of the RDS? What is the IP? First, i would give a very wide range for the rules e.g. inbound and outbound is 0.0.0.0/0 on the RDS and in the EC2 too. Can you please check with these settings?

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

Two issues could be causing this:

1) RDS attached security group inbound rules not accepting your EC2 instance requests. Make sure RDS attached security group --> "inbound" rules allow access to **RDS port** from **EC2 instance**.

2) RDS itself is down, which I suspect not in this case.

NOTE:: Don't ever open inbound-> "ports" to whole world (except in needed cases). Limit port traffic to known IP (or) network.

Comment: Re point 1. Could this be the case even though I can connect to the RDS database quite happily from my local machine?

Re point 2. No, it's definitely I have done wrong or not done!

Comment: It could, if you opened RDS port only for your local machine and restricting access from other ips.